# how to apply media Query in css3 with html5 form

Tags: html, css

i have made html5 form using css but in trouble to apply Media Query in form.plz help

```
<div class="form">  
<form action="Login.jsp" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required/>
```

`<button>login</button>`

```
Not registered? <a href="RegisterForm.jsp">Create an account</a></p>
```

**style.css**

Comment: where is the CSS that you want to apply? and to achieve what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that ? Did you google search before posting your question ?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .form .input{
       width:100px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .form .input{
       width:50px;
    }
}
```